# Android Studio 2.3 / 2.4 fails with android gradle plugin 2.4.0-alpha3

Tags: android, gradle, adb

Had multiple issues since I migrated to android-O and Java8. One of them made it impossible to install the .apk.

Restarting adb by

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

had no effect.

A bit weird is the fact that the project failed the install even after stepping back to N in Android Studio 2.3. I tried a real device, Genymotion and AVD: all failed saying

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
>    Expected configuration ':app:_debugJackPlugin' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

and

> Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
>   Error while Installing APK

After changing the project gradle from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

the app gets installed as it should. 
Has anybody a suggestion what exactly causes the above errors (as I said, adb seems to stop working completely on my osx)

Comment: using `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` ?

Comment: nope, distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip, should I change?

Comment: This issue occurs my studio also. Maybe studio having this bug, we can post this issue with Developer Preview Portal as a bug. There is a possibility of the accurate solution for this. The Same project is running properly in Preview O build.